# how can I read csv.zstd files on hive 3 on hadoop 3.x.y?

Tags: hadoop, hive, zstd

I have files **.csv.zstd**

it is like this :

```
col1|col2
1,2
```

so i create table on hive :

```
create external table test_zstd (
col1 bigint,
col2 bigint
) row format delimited fields terminated by '|' 
stored as textfile
location 'hdfs://test/test_zstd'
tblproperties(
'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

But when i select that table it brings 10 rows ( i have just 1 data line in my file) and all columns are null but just first columns is not empty which is different chars like **?*?...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i change the file name to **.csv.zstd** to **.csv.zst** it works.

It is not able to work with zstd extensions